# Adding a new page in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

Im trying to add a new page in ionic3 by adding this to my app.module.ts file:

```
import { Welcome }  from '../pages/welcome/welcome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    Welcome
...
```

But i keep receiving this error:

Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'  compiler.es5.js:1694:21
    syntaxError compiler.es5.js:1694:21
    CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata/< compiler.es5.js:15574
    forEach self-hosted:269:13
    CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata compiler.es5.js:15572
    JitCompiler.prototype._loadModules compiler.es5.js:26958:25
    JitCompiler.prototype.*compileModuleAndComponents compiler.es5.js:26931
    JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync compiler.es5.js:26860
    PlatformRef*.prototype.*bootstrapModuleWithZone core.es5.js:4536
    PlatformRef*.prototype.bootstrapModule core.es5.js:4522
    [195] main.ts:5
    **webpack_require** bootstrap 19baac5cbc8da0ce0137:54
    webpackJsonpCallback bootstrap 19baac5cbc8da0ce0137:25

How can i add a new page in Ionic 3?

Comment: Please add the code for welcome page to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLI easier, type from cmd and in the project directory `ionic g page welcome`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, you're just pushing a crappy scaffolding tool in lieu of understanding what the very specific error is.

Comment: This is the preferred method according to Ionic. Also the question is 'How can i add a new page in Ionic 3? ' therefore it perfectly answers the question.

Comment: I don't care what ionic recommends. The point is you need to understand why the error occurs. It is almost certain that the import is not being exported correctly if at all. This is a language level question you has nothing to do with the framework at all. The framework is just telling you about the error.